# I have an xml document that has a bunch of sibling records and I am trying to get the value of a sibling when I am

Tags: xml, xpath, element, siblings

I have a

My XML:

```
<Transaction>
    <Record Name = "SENDER" RecNum = "1">
        <Segment_Tag>SENDER</Segment_Tag>
        <SENDER01>5499953664103</SENDER01>
        <SENDER02>UTILMD</SENDER02>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "BGM" RecNum = "2">
        <Segment_Tag>BGM</Segment_Tag>
        <BGM01>E44</BGM01>
        <BGM03>260</BGM03>
        <BGM05>SIS20170802181883607</BGM05>
        <BGM06>9</BGM06>
        <BGM07>NA</BGM07>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "DTM" RecNum = "3">
        <Segment_Tag>DTM</Segment_Tag>
        <DTM01>137</DTM01>
        <DTM02>201708021227</DTM02>
        <DTM03>203</DTM03>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "DTM" RecNum = "4">
        <Segment_Tag>DTM</Segment_Tag>
        <DTM01>735</DTM01>
        <DTM02>+0100</DTM02>
        <DTM03>406</DTM03>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "MKS" RecNum = "5">
        <Segment_Tag>MKS</Segment_Tag>
        <MKS01>23</MKS01>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "NAD" RecNum = "6">
        <Segment_Tag>NAD</Segment_Tag>
        <NAD01>MR</NAD01>
        <NAD02>5499953664103</NAD02>
        <NAD04>9</NAD04>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "NAD" RecNum = "7">
        <Segment_Tag>NAD</Segment_Tag>
        <NAD01>MS</NAD01>
        <NAD02>5414490000504</NAD02>
        <NAD04>9</NAD04>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "IDE" RecNum = "8">
        <Segment_Tag>IDE</Segment_Tag>
        <IDE01>24</IDE01>
        <IDE02>SIS20170802181883607</IDE02>
        <Record Name = "IDEDTM" RecNum = "9">
            <Segment_Tag>IDEDTM</Segment_Tag>
            <DTM201>97</DTM201>
            <DTM202>201708012300</DTM202>
            <DTM203>203</DTM203>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "STS" RecNum = "10">
            <Segment_Tag>STS</Segment_Tag>
            <STS01>7</STS01>
            <STS02>64</STS02>
            <STS05>BA5</STS05>
            <STS06>BEL</STS06>
            <STS07>260</STS07>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "LOC" RecNum = "11">
            <Segment_Tag>LOC</Segment_Tag>
            <LOC01>172</LOC01>
            <LOC02>541449020703505315</LOC02>
            <LOC04>9</LOC04>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "IDERFF" RecNum = "12">
            <Segment_Tag>IDERFF</Segment_Tag>
            <RFF01>TN</RFF01>
            <RFF02>281945</RFF02>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "IDENAD" RecNum = "13">
            <Segment_Tag>IDENAD</Segment_Tag>
            <NAD101>DDQ</NAD101>
            <NAD102>5425037700016</NAD102>
            <NAD104>9</NAD104>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "BGM" RecNum = "14">
        <Segment_Tag>BGM</Segment_Tag>
        <BGM01>414</BGM01>
        <BGM05>ARI20170802225703376</BGM05>
        <BGM06>9</BGM06>
        <BGM07>NA</BGM07>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "DTM" RecNum = "15">
        <Segment_Tag>DTM</Segment_Tag>
        <DTM01>137</DTM01>
        <DTM02>201708021228</DTM02>
        <DTM03>203</DTM03>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "DTM" RecNum = "16">
        <Segment_Tag>DTM</Segment_Tag>
        <DTM01>735</DTM01>
        <DTM02>+0100</DTM02>
        <DTM03>406</DTM03>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "MKS" RecNum = "17">
        <Segment_Tag>MKS</Segment_Tag>
        <MKS01>23</MKS01>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "NAD" RecNum = "18">
        <Segment_Tag>NAD</Segment_Tag>
        <NAD01>MR</NAD01>
        <NAD02>5499953664103</NAD02>
        <NAD04>9</NAD04>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "NAD" RecNum = "19">
        <Segment_Tag>NAD</Segment_Tag>
        <NAD01>MS</NAD01>
        <NAD02>5414490000504</NAD02>
        <NAD04>9</NAD04>
    </Record>
    <Record Name = "IDE" RecNum = "20">
        <Segment_Tag>IDE</Segment_Tag>
        <IDE01>24</IDE01>
        <IDE02>ARI20170802225703376</IDE02>
        <Record Name = "IDEDTM" RecNum = "21">
            <Segment_Tag>IDEDTM</Segment_Tag>
            <DTM201>92</DTM201>
            <DTM202>201707142300</DTM202>
            <DTM203>203</DTM203>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "STS" RecNum = "22">
            <Segment_Tag>STS</Segment_Tag>
            <STS01>E01</STS01>
            <STS03>260</STS03>
            <STS04>39</STS04>
            <STS05>E35</STS05>
            <STS07>260</STS07>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "LOC" RecNum = "23">
            <Segment_Tag>LOC</Segment_Tag>
            <LOC01>172</LOC01>
            <LOC02>541449060016130774</LOC02>
            <LOC04>9</LOC04>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "IDERFF" RecNum = "24">
            <Segment_Tag>IDERFF</Segment_Tag>
            <RFF01>TN</RFF01>
            <RFF02>172140000045770</RFF02>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "IDECCI" RecNum = "25">
            <Segment_Tag>IDECCI</Segment_Tag>
            <CCI02>E14</CCI02>
            <CCI04>260</CCI04>
            <Record Name = "IDECAV" RecNum = "26">
                <Segment_Tag>IDECAV</Segment_Tag>
                <CAV01>B18</CAV01>
                <CAV02>BEL</CAV02>
                <CAV03>260</CAV03>
            </Record>
        </Record>
        <Record Name = "IDENAD" RecNum = "27">
            <Segment_Tag>IDENAD</Segment_Tag>
            <NAD101>IT</NAD101>
            <NAD111>RUE JOSEPH DECOOMAN</NAD111>
            <NAD112>89 221</NAD112>
            <NAD115>GREZ-DOICEAU</NAD115>
            <NAD116>1390</NAD116>
            <NAD117>BE</NAD117>
        </Record>
    </Record>
</Transaction>
```

My code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Transaction/Record[@Name='IDE']" >
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="../Record[@Name='BGM']/BGM01.='414'">
                <xsl:call-template name="ChangeResponse"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="../Record[@Name='BGM']/BGM01.='406'">
                <xsl:call-template name="DropRequest"/>
        </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that BGM and IDE are siblings and when IDE is my current node, I need to go up to the parent to get to the BGM record and this causes only the first B GM value to be returned.  I am trying to find a way to get the BGM value that is directly preceding the IDE value.  I tried using preceding-sibling but that looks at the preceding IDE value and then the BGM value before that.  I need to stay within the current node of each IDE and then evaluate the value of the previous BGM but BGM is a sibling of IDE so not sure how I use xpath to get the B GM when I am starting at the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the `xsl:for-each select="Transaction/Record[@Name='IDE']"` you should be able to use `preceding-sibling::Record[@Name = 'BGM'][1]` to find the first such preceding sibling starting from the current `Record`. So in your sample for `Record Name = "IDE" RecNum = "8"` it would select `Record Name = "BGM" RecNum = "2"` for instance.

Comment: I was not using the [1] initially after the BGM and it was not working but I found another post that had the [1].